# counter on SQL SELECT statement based on the values of the current line

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL table (first table) where this table stores the orders of a specific shop. I am not sure if it's possible but I want to produce a view like the second table.

The field orderNumber hold the number of a specific order. The lines that have the same order number means that belongs to the same order.

So based on the orderNumber and the type of the first table I want to produce the field dealCounter (see second table) where counts the numbers of deals of each order and assigns the same number of dealCounter to all the lines tha belongs to the same order.

Each time we find type 12 then we increase the dealCounter by one. If we change the orderNumber then reset the dealCounter.

I have tried to use the `rank()` function but I couldn't manage the dealCounter and set the values that I want.

Does any way which can solve my problem?

```
menuid  type  orderNumber  storeNumber  lineNumber
---------------------------------------------------
10       12    100122       10          0
8        9     100122       10          1
5        9     100122       10          2
3        9     100122       10          3
11       12    100122       10          4
5        9     100122       10          5
3        9     100122       10          6
10       12    100122       10          7
8        9     100122       10          8
5        9     100122       10          9
3        9     100122       10          10
10       12    100123       10          0
8        9     100123       10          1
5        9     100123       10          2
3        9     100123       10          3
11       12    100123       10          4
5        9     100123       10          5
3        9     100123       10          6


dealCounter  menuid  type  orderNumber  storeNumber  lineNumber
---------------------------------------------------------------
1            10       12    100122       10           0
1            8        9     100122       10           1
1            5        9     100122       10           2
1            3        9     100122       10           3
2            11       12    100122       10           4
2            5        9     100122       10           5
2            3        9     100122       10           6
3            10       12    100122       10           7
3            8        9     100122       10           8
3            5        9     100122       10           9
3            3        9     100122       10           10
1            10       12    100123       10           0
1            8        9     100123       10           1
1            5        9     100123       10           2
1            3        9     100123       10           3
2            11       12    100123       10           4
2            5        9     100123       10           5
2            3        9     100123       10           6
```

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: `group by` and `count()` didn't help?

Comment: Which column defines order in your table, is there an auto-increment `PK`?

Comment: Also, which *specific* version of SQL Server are you using, 2008, 2012, ...?

Comment: You must define an order or rows. sql tables are not ordered, they are sets. How do you know that second type=12 is the second?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008. The columns that defines the order of the table is the orderNumber and the lineNumber which is not included in my example...

Comment: @FlorinGhita each time i found type=12 I have to increase the dealCounter by one otherwise stays same..

Comment: You should include lineNumber in your example, that's going to be a pretty important column for the solution.

Comment: You have right @AaronBertrand, I just have added the lineNumber column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t3.cnt AS dealCounter, menuid, type,  orderNumber, storeNumber
FROM mytable AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 12 THEN 1 END) AS cnt
   FROM mytable AS t2
   WHERE t1.orderNumber = t2.orderNumber 
         AND t2.lineNumber <= t1.lineNumber) AS t3
```

For every row of `mytable` we apply `CROSS APPLY` operator, so as to get the count of `type=12` records that *precede or coincide with* the row and fall within the same `orderNumber` slice.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2713d/1)

Comment: @user2242558 I think that in this case either you have not correctly applied the query to your actual data, or your actual data is not correctly reflected on the sample data of the OP. Have you checked the sqlfiddle I made?

Comment: Yes I just checked the sqlfiddle and looks ok but when I run the SQL script in my real DB is not working. Below is what I am trying:          'SELECT t3.cnt AS dealCounter, menuuid, menuname, n_type, orderitemtype, n_ordernum, n_line
FROM OrderDetails3_vw 
AS t1
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN n_type = 12 THEN 1 END) AS cnt
   FROM OrderDetails3_vw AS t2
   WHERE t1.n_ordernum = t2.n_ordernum 
         AND t2.n_line <= t1.n_line
         AND t1.thedate > '2014-01-31 00:00:00.000' and t1.thedate < '2014-02-02 00:00:00.000') AS t3'

Comment: @user2242558 Can you setup a sqlfiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @user2242558 As a side note, if you want to filter out some data then place the `t1.thedate > ..` and `t1.thedate < ...` predicates *outside* the `CROSS APPLY` operator.

Comment: I just have checked the sqlfiddle you made and I see that you inser wrong the lineNumber. See my example above how I set the lineNumbers...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89829/discussion-between-user2242558-and-giorgos-betsos).

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  sum(case when type=12 then 1 end) 
    over (partition by ordernumber order by lineNumber) as dealCounter, 
  menuid,  type,  orderNumber,  storeNumber
from your_table;
```

This is a running sum(we are ordering by lineNumber) considering a 1 where type=12. The counter will reset at every new orderNumber(partition by)

Edit: Used Giorgios's fiddle. Despite of your version which commenters say does not support running sum, this seems to run ok on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2713d/3).
[Result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2713d/3/0).

Comment: question is for sqlserver 2008, this is 2012 syntax

Comment: Actually, no, `sum(...) over (...)` is supported in SQL 2008.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk didn't know that. I have oracle background. So, the solution will be useful for others but not for OP.

Comment: `sum(...) over(...)` is supported in SQL Server 2008 *but without* the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I have just tried this solution but is not working correct! It gives the dealCounter=1 when type=12 otherwise it gives dealCounter=NULL

Comment: @t-clausen.dk seems to run ok on sqlfiddle..., don't know why.

Comment: I'm getting `Incorrect syntax near 'order'` error on my SQL Server R2 setup. That's strange with sqlfiddle ...

Comment: @FlorinGhita because sqlfiddle allows 2012 syntax, I have seen this before. Running sum doesn't work on sqlserver 2008.

Comment: Here is [LINK](http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server-2012.html) about running sum